# Issue in IBOutlet reference in Custom delegate method in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, delegates, iboutlet

There is one controller and we are using a segmented controller on it. There is also a right navigation bar button and now we want to show a popupView on the segmented controller on click.

So I made a custom delegate for that bar button action.

When the button is clicked then the custom delegate method fires and it is working fine.

Now if I want to access the IBOutlet of popup view in that delegate action then it shows "Nil"

Main controller containing segmented controlle, container view and right navigation bar button:

```
// this is a protocol for button click
@objc protocol ClassList {
    func classData(id:NSArray,className:NSArray)
}
// this is button action method of right navigation bar button
@IBAction func classFilter(sender: AnyObject) {
        //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.delegate?.classData(self.classID as NSArray, className: self.dataPicker as NSArray)
    //}
}
```

Segmented controller:

```
func classData(id: NSArray, className: NSArray) {
// method fire correctly
        self.pickerView.hidden = false // crash app because pickerView reference nil
    }
```

Comment: Is the outlet connected?

Comment: yes, it is connected.

Comment: need more code, cuz this works fine. try to delete `self`.

Comment: according to my knowledge it works fine but i don't know why it is giving error in my senerio . why it gives outlet reference to nil ?